# How to doubleclick and rightclick in WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

As part of project I am trying to use Selenium 2 for automation. I am facing trouble with the below

1. How do I double click on a web element using Selenium?
2. How should I right click on a web element to select an item from the menu pop up?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? Java, C# or what?

Answer (score 4):

1. There are 2 ways to double click on element:

   - using `DefaultActionSequenceBuilder` class

     ```
     IActionSequenceBuilder action = new
     DefaultActionSequenceBuilder(driver);
     action.DoubleClick(element).Build().Perform();
     ```
   - or using `WebDriverBackedSelenium` class

     ```
     ISelenium selenium=new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, driver.Url); 
     selenium.Start();
     selenium.DoubleClick("xpath=" + some_xpath);// you could use id, name, etc.
     ```
2. There is ContextMenu method in `ISelenium` interface you could use for simulating Right click. For instance:

   ```
   ISelenium selenium=new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, driver.Url);
   selenium.Start();
   selenium.ContextMenu("xpath=" + some_xpath);// you could use id, name, etc.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Double Click**

```
WebElement ele = driver.findelement(By.id("id_of_element"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver)
action.doubleClick(ele).perform();
```

**Right Click**

```
WebElement ele = driver.findelement(By.id("id_of_element"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver)
action.contextClick(ele).build().perform();
```

If you want second option on the pop up which opens after performing right click you can use below code

```
action.contextClick(ele).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).build().perform();
```